# Valid phrase seems like a double negative: 'Tú no tienes que explicar nada'

Tags: gramática

> Tú no tienes que explicar nada.

Doesn't the use of both "no" and "nada" make this a double negative?

Comment: Yes, _no… nada_ is a double negative. Unlike in English, double negatives are a natural part of Spanish – in fact, they’re mandatory. They’re not ‘supposed’ to mathematically cancel each other out and mean a positive the way they are ‘supposed’ to (but often don’t, of course) in English.

Comment: It would be easier if they taught that "nada" can also mean "anything", and not just "nothing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentece is correct as is now: it is not a double negative but the way a sentence with *nada* needs to be written down if *nada* occurs after the verb.

From [*nada*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=nada) in DPD:

> **nada**.
>   1. Pronombre indefinido que significa ‘ninguna cosa’. Los adjetivos a él referidos deben ir en masculino singular: *«Nada es nuevo en la vida»* (Paso Palinuro [Méx. 1977]); *«No observó nada extraño en el comportamiento del presunto asesino»* (Abc [Esp.] 27.11.87). Como se ve en el ejemplo anterior, **cuando va pospuesto al verbo exige que este vaya en forma negativa, precedido del adverbio *no*, o, si no, que haya en la oración algún otro elemento negativo** (*jamás*, *nunca*, *nadie*, etc.): *«Allí nunca ocurría nada»* (Quevedo Genes [Cuba 1996]); *«En esta ocasión nadie vio nada, nadie oyó nada»* (Mundo [Esp.] 22.11.94); pero si va antepuesto al verbo, este no debe ir en forma negativa: *«Este hecho nada tiene de singular»* (Abc [Esp.] 21.6.86). Es, pues, incorrecto utilizar nada como sujeto antepuesto a un verbo en forma negativa, como ocurre a veces por influjo del catalán o del francés: *«Este es el camino y nada no nos moverá»* (DTarragona@ [Esp.] 4.5.05); debió decirse *nada nos moverá*.